# Conditionally displaying datatable values in jsf

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I have column data ( e.g. 15 product records) as drop down in JSF. I want to hide one of the record(one product) based on the user login location. How to achieve it?

I am using jsf 1.2

Thanks,

Raj

Comment: Where do you store the user login location? Or is it something you're currently not doing?

Comment: @XtremeBiker it is stored in one of the DTO , we are getting it from request parameter.